# vba access table not updated from a sql string

Tags: vba, ms-access, refresh, relationship

I'm a "Sunday" developer trying to create a datatabase in MS Access about "writers and books", with relation many to many.
I have a table "books", a table "authors" and a middle table for the many to many relation.
I wrote some lines to update the "middle" table, with a combobox on a subform  (book) of a form (author).
The problem is: when i add, through the combobox, a new "book", with code updating the table "book" and the Middle table, the refresh is not immediate, so I cannot find the new value on the combobox immediately but only after have pushed the icon "refresh all" on the menu bar.

```
   Private Sub ID_COL_LIBRO_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
   On errot GoTo Error_Handler
   Dim IntAnswer As Integer
   Dim Sqlstring As String
   IntAnswer = MsgBox(" " & NewData & " è un nuovo nominativo.  " & vbCrLf _
   & "vuoi aggiungerlo adesso ?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Nome Sconosciuto")
   Select Case IntAnswer
       Case vbYes
           Sqlstring = "INSERT INTO LIBRI (TITOLO) VALUES ( '" & NewData & "')"
           DoCmd.SetWarnings False
           DoCmd.RunSQL Sqlstring
           Dim datab As DAO.Database
           Dim rcslibri As DAO.Recordset
           Dim strultrec As String
           Set prova_relazione_m_a_m = CurrentDb
           Set rstlibri = prova_relazione_m_a_m.OpenRecordset("LIBRI")
           rstlibri.MoveLast
           strlastrifliblibro = rstlibri!RIF_LIB_LIBRO
           Dim str_idcolaut As String
           str_idcolaut = Me!RIF_AUT_AUTORE.Value
           Sqlstring = "INSERT INTO tab_collegamento (id_col_libro, id_col_autore) VALUES ( '" & strlastrifliblibro & "','" & str_idcolaut & "')"
           DoCmd.RunSQL Sqlstring
           DoCmd.SetWarnings True
           rstlibri.Close
           Response = acDataErrAdded
       Case vbNo
           MsgBox "Allora seleziona un nome dalla lista.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Selezione errata"
   End Select
   Response = acDataErrContinue
exit_procedure:
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Exit Sub
Error_Handler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ", " & error_Description
Resume exit_procedure
Resume
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you need to enter more data about new book than just its title? Why not open a form for entry of this record? Review https://blueclawdatabase.com/notinlist-event-code/

Comment: You need to `.Requery` the datasource to get the updates. If your combo's source is a query, you need to call its requery method to update the items, e.g. `Combo.Requery`. The same goes for the form.

Comment: @KostasK., acDataErrAdded is supposed requery combobox. Requery command should not also be needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.ComboBox.NotInList

Comment: @Gianni, should add `Option Explicit` at top of code modules. Can make this happen by default in new modules with application Options setting. Have you step debugged code?

Comment: Best practice is to declare all variables at top of procedure. There is typo error in On errort GoTo Error_Handler. Indentation makes code easier to read - I have edited for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your form/subform design is not correct. Books should not be a subform of Authors. Books and Authors are lookup tables for data entry into junction table (BooksAuthors). Usual approach would be:

1. main form bound to Books, subform bound to junction table with a combobox to select author; or
2. main form bound to Authors, subform bound to junction table with a combobox to select book; or
3. one form bound to junction table with two comboboxes to select book and author.

Then use NotInList event for entering new records to Books or Authors 'on the fly' during data entry to BookAuthors.

Comment: Indeed, I set the subform source on the junction table . The problem is that when I select a value not listed in the combobox (which the source is  a query of LIBRI and JUNCTION table), it doesn't update the list. I noticed that if I push "update all" on the menu bar, the combobox list updates. I tried to insert the code to requery (I tried everything, on the combobox, on the subform, on the form, on the query, all) but a message error gives error run-time 2115, saying that can not save the data because of macro or function set on beforeupdate or "valido se" property. Sorry for bad english

Comment: Your narrative seemed to say subform is Books. Why is combobox RowSource joining LIBRI and JUNCTION tables? What is the SQL? Is it with INNER JOIN? What is code in BeforeUpdate event? "valido se" is what property - ValidationRule? Edit question with all this relevant info.

Comment: I wrote mistakenly that the subform was based on libri though it’s properly based on a query that considers fields from three tables (AUTORI, LIBRI, and the junction table). Here’s the sql:

     SELECT AUTORI.AUTORE, AUTORI.RIF_AUT_AUTORE, TAB_COLLEGAMENTO.ID_COL_AUTORE, 
             TAB_COLLEGAMENTO.ID_COL_LIBRO, LIBRI.TITOLO, LIBRI.RIF_LIB_LIBRO
             FROM AUTORI INNER JOIN (LIBRI INNER JOIN TAB_COLLEGAMENTO ON LIBRI. 
             [RIF_LIB_LIBRO] = TAB_COLLEGAMENTO.[ID_COL_LIBRO]) ON AUTORI.[RIF_AUT_AUTORE] = 
             TAB_COLLEGAMENTO.[ID_COL_AUTORE];

Comment: Why use query and not just bind to table? I think it is INNER JOIN that is causing issue with combobox RowSource which is also a query with INNER JOIN. INNER JOIN requires related records in both tables for data to show. This likely gets 'out of sync' in data entry process because of INNER JOIN. Should edit question with query info, not a comment or answer. Edit other info in question as well.